# Touch-ability of an Invisible View

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I have a view which is invisible for some part of the code.
Even though I can't see the view, I am able to touch and perform actions through it.

I have tried setting Visibility as "GONE" but that hinders with my layout.

```
TextView help1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.help1);
help1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

I want to disable all actions on this view.

Comment: Put transparent of this view and then click listener on this view

Comment: try to disabling the view (setEnabled(false))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
help1.setClickable(false);
help1.setFocusable(false);
help1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

This should disable your view actions;

Answer (score 0):

Put transparent of this view and then click listener on this view
Because invisible view will also occupy space

```
TextView help1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.help1);
help1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#55FF0000"));
```

Answer (score 0):

set .setEnable of your view false disable the view from accessing

```
help1.setEnabled(false);
help1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```